# Ruby Net::SSH undefined method 'shell'

Tags: ruby, ssh

I'm trying to log into a remote machine using SSH in my Ruby code and then trying to cd into another directory once I SSHed in. Here is my Ruby code to do it

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'rubygems'
require 'needle'

Net::SSH.start('host', 'shui', :password => "password") do |ssh|
   output = ssh.exec!("hostname")
   shell = ssh.shell.open
   shell.pwd
   shell.cd "/svn"
   puts shell.pwd
end
```

when I run my script, it gives me this error:

```
testssh.rb:8:in `block in <main>': undefined method `shell' ... (NoMethodError)
```

I'm pretty sure I've installed the gems that are needed to do this. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no `shell` method in `Net:SSH v2`, the yielded object is a  [Net::SSH::Connection::Session](http://net-ssh.github.com/ssh/v2/api/classes/Net/SSH/Connection/Session.html).

This `net-ssh` extension gives you the feature you are looking for: https://github.com/mitchellh/net-ssh-shell

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your version?

```
gem list --local | grep ssh
```

i have 2.5.2

I found multiple references online, but you should use:

http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/ssh/v2/api/classes/Net/SSH.html

here is the reference to v1

http://net-ssh.github.com/ssh/v1/chapter-5.html

the later, uses the shell method. But i don't think you have that gem installed.

So have a look at the 1st one (v2).  Thats working fine for me.